# В карусели раскрывается только часть списков

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Приветствую. Есть у меня owl карусель и в каждом элементе раскрывающийся список по кнопке подробнее, но почему-то не все элементы раскрываются. Тут я схематично представил один элемент, а проблему можно увидеть [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/wh6780v2/) Не могу понять: если вводить количество item на странице 3, то раскрываются 2 списка(на большом экране), если 2, то раскрываются 3, если 1, то тоже 3.. По ссылке раскрывается так вообще только один - что за черт с этой каруселью?

```js
$('#correspondents').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsiveClass: true,
  navigationText: ["", ""],
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    680: {
      items: 2
    },
    1024: {
      items: 3
    }
  }
});

$("#correspondent-1-more").click(function() {
  $("#correspondent-1-group").show();

});
```

```css
.about-grid-john {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #D4D5D9;
  padding: 1em;
}
.about-grid img {
  width: 100%;
}
p.para {
  color: #5E6C76;
  margin: 3px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#correspondent-1-group,
#correspondent-2-group,
#correspondent-3-group,
#correspondent-4-group {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel" id="correspondents">
  <div class="correspondent">
    <img src="#" alt=" " />
    <div class="about-grid-john">
      <div class="john">
        <h4>Титул</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="social-icons">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href class="facebook"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href class="twitter"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <p id="correspondent-1-more">Подробнее</p>
      <div id="correspondent-1-group">
        <p class="para">бла-бла-бла</p>
        <p id="correspondent-1-break">Свернуть</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте названия тегов в выборке.
Пример:

```
 $("p#correspondent-2-more"),   
 $("div#correspondent-2-group")
```

Comment: супер! а почему так получается?

Comment: Бэс понятия :))

Comment: Сравните вывод в консоль этих двух селекторов http://jsfiddle.net/oe9uybd8/ ради интереса.